# Regex query efficient?

Tags: regex

I came up with the below regex expression to look for terms like Password,Passphrase,Pass001 etc and the word following it. Is it efficient or can it be made better? Thanks for the help

```
"([Pp][aA][sS][Ss]([wW][oO][rR][dD][sS]?|[Pp][hH][rR][aA][sS][eE])?|[Pp]([aA][sS]([sS])?)?[wW][Dd])[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[\s\:\-\=\_\/\@\&\'\[\(\+\*\r\n\)\]]+\S*"
```

I will be using it to scan files upto 300K for these terms. When I try now to scan with these expression a whole C: drive it takes 5 hours or worse case I have encountered, 5 days

Comment: More efficient as in runtime or number of characters used in the regex? The answer to both is most likely yes, but you will need to be way more specific about what you're scanning for. Also, scanning your whole C: drive is much more worrisome and impactful than regex. But, again, hard to help without more details.

Comment: Efficient in runtime. This is to identify if passwords are stored on the drive in clear text (where it shouldnt be) in text,xls,doc,rtf,csv,ini.

Comment: What program do you use for regex matching. Regexes can be compiled to run extremely fast...

Comment: Nessus - compliance check

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following enhancement:

```
(?i)p(?:ass(?:words?|phrase)?|(?:ass?)?wd)[0-9]{0,3}[-\s:=_\/@&'\]\[()+*\r\n]\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/orfA2h/1)

Instead of `[sS]`, you may make the regex case insensitive by adding `(?i)` case insensitive modifier. Use corresponding option in your software if it does not work like this.

Make sure your alternations do not match at the same location in the string. It is not quite easy here, but `p` at the start of each alternative in the first group decreases the regex efficiency. So, move it outside (e.g. `(?:pass|port)` => `p(ass|ort)`).

Use non-capturing groups rather than capturing ones if you are not going to access submatches, that also has a slight impact on performance.

Use limiting quantifiers instead of repeating `?` quantified patterns. Instead of `a?a?a?`, use `a{0,3}`.

Do not overescape chars inside the character class. I only left `\/`, `\]` and `\[` as I am not sure what regex flavor you are using, it might appear you can avoid escaping at all.

Note that a performance penalty is big if you have consecutive non-fixed width patterns that may match the same type of chars. You have `[\s\:\-\=\_\/\@\&\'\[\(\+\*\r\n\)\]]+\S*`: `[\s\:\-\=\_\/\@\&\'\[\(\+\*\r\n\)\]]+` matches 1 or more special chars and `\S*` matches 0 or more chars other than whitespace that also matches some chars matched by the preceding pattern. Remove the `+` from the preceding subpattern.